# How to Publish Xamarin android app that is built with multiple APKs per ABI?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I try to publish a Xamarin android app that is built with multiple APKs per ABI setting enabled in Visual Studio, it outputs just one fat apk instead of multiple, why is it like that? and what should I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `Android Options`, you have to select the right configuration (Release vs. Debug and Platform).

Also check for selected architectures.

Comment: I know, I have selected release with proper configuration, that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build this project:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/OneABIPerAPK

which builds three APK's, one for each ABI. Then compare the settings for your project against it.

Docs [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/build-abi-specific-apks/)

Comment: when I build it works fine for me, ie: it out puts 3 apks for each ABI but when I publish it doesn't work like that

Answer (score 0):

Here is **C# console app** example of how to build Android with custom **versionCode**, **versionName** and **packedgeName** separated by **ABI**

https://github.com/JTOne123/OnePackagePerABI

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)